Are quantum numbers only applied to hydrogen?
I read on wiki that

Four quantum numbers can describe an electron energy level in a hydrogen-like atom completely:

However I see quantum numbers applied to all of the periodic table. For example here:

What is going on?

What is the actual issue you're seeing? You can describe electron energy levels in more-complex atoms with more quantum numbers. For a very simple one like hydrogen the amount of required quantum numbers is four. Is that not consistent with both things here?

All states of a central potential can be labelled by $\ell$ and $m$ so certainly not limited to hydrogen.

@controlgroup I think I got confused because after it says we use four numbers to describe electrons in a hydrogen atom it states "to describe different systems different quantum numbers are needed." Do they just mean different values but not different quantum number types?

@ZeroTheHero I think that's the crux of the problem: central potentials are pretty much synonymous with hydrogen-like atoms, so OP needs someone to explain what these things mean, to what extent they are approximations, maybe something more along those lines as well

@QuantumMechanic hmmm…. not sure I would agree that central potentials are synonymous with hydrogen, and not sure I understand the original question that way either but the OP added interesting clarifications.

@ZeroTheHero perhaps I can clarify: one learns from the hydrogen atom about quantum numbers. Why should the same quantum numbers be applicable to other atoms? The "central potential" says treat the nucleus as effectively a point source. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen-like_atom says that you can lump all non-valence electrons into this central potential. And true atoms have electron-electron interactions that are neglected by these methods and thus by these four quantum numbers. The point is that the latter label eigenfunctions of the angular momentum operators

Quantum mechanics is at its heart a labelling problem: you are looking for a way to give a sensible name to states.  Now you could choose to call the ground state of hydrogen as the “Hero state” but that’s not terribly insightful, and you’d have to remember a dictionary of individual names.
Now one would prefer not to name states by things are change in time, just like it’s not really useful to name humans by their heights or their weights.  Mr. 140kg isn’t very insightful because the weight of someone can change over time.
So we want: meaningful names that don’t change in time.  What do we have?
“Good names” are basically quantum numbers.  An obvious good name is the energy of a state as energy is conserved (in a closed system).  That’s not enough because there might be many states with a given energy, just like there are many Baggins at Bag Ends.  So we need more “good names”, like angular momentum $\ell$ (this works well for central potential as angular momentum is conserved) and also its projection $m$.
The specific values they take depend on the system: for hydrogen, the values of $\ell$ go from $0$ to $n-1$, and the value of $m$ from $-\ell$ to $+\ell$ for every allowed $\ell$.  So that’s 3 quantum numbers.  The 4th is related to spin, and there is no classical way of understanding spin.
For the 3D harmonic oscillator, the values of $\ell$ start at $n$ and go down in steps of $2$ until one reaches $0$ or $1$.  In general, the range of $\ell$ depends on the potential but basically always so that $n$ and sometimes $\ell$ uniquely identify the energy, $\ell$ uniquely identifies the angular momentum, and $m$ its projection; here again there is a final quantum number related to spin.
There are other “types” of quantum numbers.  Parity is an example that is useful for reflection-symmetric potentials: we talk of even or odd states.  Roughly speaking, quantum numbers can be additive (like projections of the angular momentum), multiplicative (like parity), or of some other kind, like $\ell$: in a multi-particle state, the total value of $\ell$ is not the sum or product of the values of $\ell$ of the individual components.  In the standard model of particles, particles are given quantum numbers that have nothing to do with the spatial properties of the particles
In the particular example you give, there are rules for obtaining $m$ and also rules for obtaining $\ell$.  These were initially obtained empirically but the rules have been validated through multi-electron computations.
There are also rules for nuclear levels which are quite different, because the nuclear interactions are quite different from electronic and Coulomb interactions valid in multi-electron atoms.
So: quantum numbers are just a way of identifying useful properties of states so we can get some information about the state just from knowing the quantum numbers.  There is no reason to limit their use to hydrogen and indeed great progress has been done by extending the idea to other properties of multi-particle states or properties of elementary particles.
